# Making a dependency configurable at runtime in Symfony 2?

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, doctrine-orm, inversion-of-control, dbal

In my reusable bundle, I can specify a connection name (Doctrine DBAL connection):

```
# config.yml
my_bundle:
    connection: ~ # or "default", or "my_connection"
```

In the extension, I'm *aliasing* it:

```
// MyBundleExtension.php
$container->setAlias(
    'my_bundle.connection',
    'doctrine.dbal.'.$config['connection'].'_connection'
);
```

And injecting it where needed (4-5 services in the bundle). All works fine.

Unfortunatly, it turns out that **connection should (may) be changed at runtime**, i.e. after the user as been authenticated (i.e with HTTP basic authentication). When username is `foo`, then use  `foo_database`, when `bar` then `bar_database`.

*My solution (workaround):*

Right now I'm **changing it using the event system**: when something in the bundle uses a `Connection` object, I emit an event, i.e `MyBundle::BAR` event. A listener can change the connection using `setConnection(Connection $connection)`. Then in my bundle, I use the updated connection calling `getConnection()`.

This solution however forces me to listen to every event that need to change the connection. What if i forgot to listen to `MyBundle::FOO` event? My application would not work as expected and bugs would be difficult to understand and track.

Is there a good way to solve this problem?

Comment: I know Sylius does some magic with container parameters, so that interfaces can be defined in Doctrine mappings and a base model class can be used with Doctrine ORM or Doctrine MongoDB ODM, without having to specify `Entity` and `Document` classes respectively. I think this can be done by overriding `MyBundle::boot()` and manipulating the parameters there.

Comment: @AdamElsodaney hey, thanks. Can you point me to the right class or file?